# How to write a criteria or HQL for generic scrollable results in Hibernate?

Tags: java, hibernate, hql, criteria

In my current project of batch processing, I need to write a criteria or HQL for obtain generic scrollable results, in order to process entity one by one. Once processed, the entity id will be saved as checkpoint, called `checkpointId`. And if the job need to be restarted, then another scrollable query will be created and will be started with the `checkpointId`. In this batch job, all kinds of entity having `@Id` are accepted.

If I translate into SQL, it will be similar to the below statement, with `FETCH NEXT`.

```
SELECT * FROM my_table WHERE id > checkpoint_id LIMIT 1
```

If I implement it in Java, it becomes :

```
Class<?> entityType = MyClass.class;
ScrollableResults scrollableResults = session
        .createCriteria( entityType )
        .setCacheable( false )
        .setFetchSize( 1 )
        //
        // TODO: where id > checkpointId
        //
        .setMaxResults( maxResults )
        .scroll( ScrollMode.FORWARD_ONLY );
```

But the problems are :

- How to implement the `WHERE` condition in Hibernate session ?
- How to know the identifier type of the current entity ?

I'm using criteria. If HQL is easier, then I can accept HQL. Hibernate version is 5x.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
Class<?> entityType = MyClass.class;
ClassMetadata md = sessionFactory.getClassMetadata( entityType );
ScrollableResults scrollableResults = session
        .createCriteria( entityType )
        .setCacheable( false )
        .setFetchSize( 1 )
        .add( Restrictions.gt( md.getIdentifierPropertyName(), checkpointId ))
        .setMaxResults( maxResults )
        .scroll( ScrollMode.FORWARD_ONLY );
```